# Will Ubuntu for Android be fully open source?

Tags: open-source, ubuntu-for-android

I am truly happy that Ubuntu-For-Android is more than a prototype. Yet, I'm confused. I failed to fully realise this:

1. Going to be fully open source?
2. Released eventually to the community to work on?

Cheers, and keep up the amazing work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Silber said Ubuntu for Android would be released under an open source
>   license, but that Canonical expects it to mostly be pre-installed on
>   specific hardware.

-- Jane Silber, Canonical CEO in [PC Pro](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/373024/canonical-puts-ubuntu-on-android-smartphones)

Comment: As soon as I get my hands on the source I plan on trying to get it to work with my phone and I would be incredibly surprised if other developers didn't mod their phones to run Ubuntu for Android as well. It's already been done with vanilla Ubuntu on [at least one Android phone](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=720622)

Answer (score 3):

> The other problem is that while Canonical is pushing the build to
>   hardware manufacturers and mobile carriers, it has no plans to release
>   it to the general public for independent development. This means that
>   you won’t see a CyanogenMod ROM with this functionality built into it.
>   While Ubuntu is open source, Canonical plans to control the release of
>   this version. It’s possible that, given the ingenuity of Android
>   users, one day there will be a leaked build, but such a thing wouldn’t
>   be endorsed by the company.

http://www.extremetech.com/computing/119031-canonical-reveals-ubuntu-for-android/2

Comment: My take on that is that Canonical isn't going to distribute binaries that you can flash onto your phone, but that the source code will be there. It's not so much a matter of a "leaked build" but more like someone taking the time to pull the opensourced components together and producing an unofficial build.

Comment: My guess is that the source code will never be there.. I guess that canonical does not want Ubuntu to be wasted with Samsung Touchwizz, HTC Sense, and other craps...

Comment: Yes, like explained in the title of the question, I am talking about Ubuntu for Android since the beginning ;-)

Comment: Ubuntu going closed source? I don't think so